# Thread of different processes communicate

Tags: pthreads

I have a process P7 and a process P5. Each process have a number of threads. The thread T5.3 must end before T7.2. I've tried with sem_wait and sem_post but it did not work. 
How can I communicate between threads of different process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use POSIX threads primitives that can be configured to be shared between processes. See e.g. accepted answer to this question: [sharing pthread mutex and condvar over process boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325146/share-condition-variable-mutex-between-processes-does-mutex-have-to-locked-be)

Se also [Manpage for pthread_condattr_getpshared, pthread_condattr_setpshared](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_condattr_setpshared.html)