# Unable to send signal using pthread_cond_signal to another process in C

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc

I am trying to implement producer-consumer problem using a two-process scenario.

Process1 — Producer, and Process2 — Consumer. The consumer process is waiting on a condition variable (`pthread_cond_wait(cond)`) and producer will send a signal to consumer via `pthread_cond_signal(cond)`.

I have gone through these links [shared mutex and condition variable across process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325146/share-condition-variable-mutex-between-processes-does-mutex-have-to-locked-be) [`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389353/do-pthread-mutexs-work-across-threads-if-in-shared-memory), everywhere it was said it is possible to use mutex and condition variable across multiple processes,

```
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
```

In this link [shared mutexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389353/do-pthread-mutexs-work-across-threads-if-in-shared-memory/2390670#2390670), as void's recommendation, it was said to check whether my system supports or not? I have checked and I got 200809 as return value of `sysconf(_SC_THREAD_PROCESS_SHARED)` which denotes my system supports `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`.

**I am trying to send `pthread_cond_signal` from producer (process-1) to consumer (Process-2).** Both producer and consumer are using the same mutex/condition variable initialized.

**However, consumer is not receiving the signal. It seems either signal is not sent or it is lost.**

Where I am making mistakes? I am using Ubuntu, gcc-4.6.3.

Here is my code.

#### Producer.c:

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <sched.h>
    #include <syscall.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <sys/mman.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>

    pthread_cond_t* condition;
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex;

    #define OKTOWRITE "/oktowrite"
    #define MESSAGE "/message"
    #define MUTEX "/lock"


    struct shared_use_st 
    {
    bool conditionSatisfied;
    };

    struct shared_use_st *shared_stuff;

    void create_shared_memory()
    {
        int shmid;
        void *shared_memory=(void *)0;
        shmid =shmget( (key_t)1234, 4096, 0666 | IPC_CREAT );

        if (shmid == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"shmget failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        shared_memory =shmat(shmid, (void *)0,0);

        if(shared_memory == (void *)-1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"shmat failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }

        shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;
    }


    int main()
    {
        int des_cond, des_msg, des_mutex;
        int mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG;

        des_mutex = shm_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

        if (des_mutex < 0) {
            perror("failure on shm_open on des_mutex");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (ftruncate(des_mutex, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)) == -1) {
            perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_mutex, 0);

        if (mutex == MAP_FAILED ) {
            perror("Error on mmap on mutex\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        des_cond = shm_open(OKTOWRITE, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

        if (des_cond < 0) {
            perror("failure on shm_open on des_cond");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (ftruncate(des_cond, sizeof(pthread_cond_t)) == -1) {
            perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
            exit(-1);
        }

        condition = (pthread_cond_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_cond_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_cond, 0);

        if (condition == MAP_FAILED ) {
            perror("Error on mmap on condition\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* set mutex shared between processes */
        pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexAttr);
        pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &mutexAttr);

        /* set condition shared between processes */
        pthread_condattr_t condAttr;
        pthread_condattr_init(&condAttr);
        pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        pthread_cond_init(condition, &condAttr);

        create_shared_memory();
        shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied=0;

        int count=0;
        while(count++<10)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
            shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied=1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

            pthread_cond_signal(condition);
            printf("signal sent to consumer, %d\n",count);

            sleep(3);
        }

        pthread_condattr_destroy(&condAttr);
        pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutexAttr);
        pthread_mutex_destroy(mutex);
        pthread_cond_destroy(condition);

        shm_unlink(OKTOWRITE);
        shm_unlink(MESSAGE);
        shm_unlink(MUTEX);

        return 0;
    }
```

#### Consumer.c:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <syscall.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

pthread_cond_t* condition;
pthread_mutex_t* mutex;

#define OKTOWRITE "/oktowrite"
#define MESSAGE "/message"
#define MUTEX "/lock"

struct shared_use_st 
{
bool conditionSatisfied;
};

struct shared_use_st *shared_stuff;

void create_shared_memory()
{
    int shmid;
    void *shared_memory=(void *)0;
    shmid =shmget( (key_t)1234, 4096, 0666 | IPC_CREAT );

    if (shmid == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"shmget failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    shared_memory =shmat(shmid, (void *)0,0);

    if(shared_memory == (void *)-1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"shmat failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    shared_stuff = (struct shared_use_st *)shared_memory;
}

int main()
{
    int des_cond, des_msg, des_mutex;
    int mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG;

    des_mutex = shm_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

    if (des_mutex < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on des_mutex");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ftruncate(des_mutex, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_mutex, 0);

    if (mutex == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on mutex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    des_cond = shm_open(OKTOWRITE, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, mode);

    if (des_cond < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on des_cond");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ftruncate(des_cond, sizeof(pthread_cond_t)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    condition = (pthread_cond_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_cond_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_cond, 0);

    if (condition == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on condition\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* set mutex shared between processes */
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexAttr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &mutexAttr);

    /* set condition shared between processes */
    pthread_condattr_t condAttr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&condAttr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    pthread_cond_init(condition, &condAttr);

    create_shared_memory();
    shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied=0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Receiver waits on for signal from hello1.c \n");

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        while(!shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied)
            pthread_cond_wait(condition, mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

        printf("Signal received, wake up!!!!!!!!\n");

        //reset
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied=0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your use of the shared memory is wrong: you are calling in both processes shm_open with O_CREATE and also ftruncate. Only one process should create the shared memory segment and resize it. The other one should attach to it.

Comment: Did you tried to share something between the two processes before working on the mutex?

Comment: @terencehill , AFIK, other process will first check whether the shared memory is already there or not. If it is already there, it won't create a new one, only attach to the existing one.

Comment: @terencehill, the problem is the updated value of conditionSatisfied is not visible in consumer process.

Comment: In which order the things happens? You truncate in both the producer and the consumer.

Comment: Moreover you are mixing the old shmget/shmat with sum_open which I find a little bit confusing

Comment: *the problem is the updated value of conditionSatisfied is not visible in consumer process.*  Look at the instructions generated and make sure the check hasn't been optimized away.  You can also add some code to emit something to `stderr` in the consumer `while` loop to verify the consumer is getting the signal.

Comment: @terencehill Also, the signal is also not sent to consumer. If I remove the predicate, while(!shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied) still consumer is not waking.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I didn't get you. I have already used gcc -O0 to disable all optimisation.

Comment: @terencehill,  first I run consumer, so it is waiting for signal from producer , then I run producer.

Comment: Ok, so the truncate in the producer is pointless, however should not be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mutex shared among processes should be initialised by only one of them**

The error is that you are initialising the *mutex* and the *condition* on both processes. However as they are shared, you should initialise them only on the **consumer**.

I also suggest not to mix the old System V *shmget/shmat* functions with the new POSIX *shm_open*.

I defined a new shared integer *shint* and which points to a shared memory initialised with *shm_open* and attached via *mmap*. *shint* is used as a flag to wait on the pthread *condition*.

In my view the **producer**, which starts after the consumer, doesn't need to truncate the memory segment and can open the shared memory with only O_RDWR. The producer takes the lock first and set *shint* to 1.

On the other hand the **consumer**, which starts first, has to create the shared memory segments and resize them with *ftruncate*. It also set the shared flag *shint* to 0 and wait on it. Also, before calling *shm_open* it is better to unlink (via shm_unlik) all used shared memory segments, to clean eventual errors on previous calls (for example if the code crash before unlinking).

I moved the initialisation of attributes for the mutex and condition at the beginning, because it seems more clear and correct.

---

**Producer.c**

```
int main()
{
    int des_cond, des_msg, des_mutex;
    int mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG;

    /* set mutex shared between processes */
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexAttr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    /* set condition shared between processes */
    pthread_condattr_t condAttr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&condAttr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    des_mutex = shm_open(MUTEX, O_RDWR, mode);

    if (des_mutex < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on des_mutex");
        exit(1);
    }

    mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_mutex, 0);

    if (mutex == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on mutex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    des_cond = shm_open(OKTOWRITE, O_RDWR, mode);

    if (des_cond < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on des_cond");
        exit(1);
    }

    condition = (pthread_cond_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_cond_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_cond, 0);

    if (condition == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on condition\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int fd = shm_open(MESSAGE, O_RDWR, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on fd");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(ftruncate(fd, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof ftruncate fd\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int *shint;
    shint = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    if (shint == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on shint\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // set ot 0
    *shint = 0;


    int count=0;
    while(count++<10)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        *shint = 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

        pthread_cond_signal(condition);
        printf("signal sent to consumer, %d\n",count);

        sleep(3);
    }

    pthread_condattr_destroy(&condAttr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutexAttr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(condition);

    shm_unlink(OKTOWRITE);
    shm_unlink(MESSAGE);
    shm_unlink(MUTEX);

    return 0;
}
```

**Consumer.c**

```
int main()
{
    int des_cond, des_msg, des_mutex;
    int mode = S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG;

    // Unlink first to clean  
    shm_unlink(MUTEX);
    shm_unlink(OKTOWRITE);
    shm_unlink(MESSAGE);

    pthread_mutexattr_t mutexAttr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexAttr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

    pthread_condattr_t condAttr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&condAttr);
    pthread_condattr_setpshared(&condAttr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);


    des_mutex = shm_open(MUTEX, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode);

    if (des_mutex < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on des_mutex");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ftruncate(des_mutex, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    mutex = (pthread_mutex_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_mutex, 0);

    if (mutex == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on mutex\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    des_cond = shm_open(OKTOWRITE, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, mode);

    if (des_cond < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on des_cond");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ftruncate(des_cond, sizeof(pthread_cond_t)) == -1) {
        perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof pthread_cond_t\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    condition = (pthread_cond_t*) mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_cond_t),PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, des_cond, 0);

    if (condition == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on condition\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int fd = shm_open(MESSAGE, O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0644);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("failure on shm_open on fd");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(ftruncate(fd, 16) == -1) {
        perror("Error on ftruncate to sizeof ftruncate fd\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    int *shint;
    shint = (int *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    if (shint == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("Error on mmap on shint\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    *shint = 0;

        if (pthread_mutex_init(mutex, &mutexAttr) != 0)    {printf("Error initi mutex"); exit(111);}
        if (pthread_cond_init(condition, &condAttr) != 0) {printf("Error initi cond");  exit(111);}

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Receiver waits on for signal from hello1.c \n");

        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        while(shint == 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(condition, mutex);
        printf("Waiting"); sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);

        printf("Signal received, wake up!!!!!!!!\n");

        break;
        //reset
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        shared_stuff->conditionSatisfied=0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks , it is working perfectly to send signal from producer to consumer. I want to send data from producer to consumer ,that's why I was using shared memory . What is your suggestion to send data ? Should I just create a shared memory using shm_open just you did shint int memory ?

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to achieve. Personally I would stick on shared memory: you can implement almost all the type of communications, just using the correct synchronisation mechanisms and the data layout of the shared memory.