# Synchronized access to data in shared memory between two processes

Tags: c, synchronization, ipc, shared-memory

I have two processes that have data in shared memory. This data is going to be updated by both of these process. I was looking for some locking mechanism between two processes. With threads it was easy to have a shared mutex lock. In my case, I tried to save the mutex variable in the shared memory, which then will be used by both processes for locking. This didn't work though. How do I share a mutex between two processes. Some say mutexes cannot be shared, use semaphores. Why mutex cannot be shared but semaphores can be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, you have to use the flag PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED:

```
pthread_mutexattr_t mattr;
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mattr);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);


// Init the shared mem barrier
if ( (rv = pthread_mutex_init(&nshared, &mattr)) != 0 ) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initiliaze the shared mutex.\n");
      return rv;
}
```

Where the variable `nshared` is mapped in shared memory.

Take a look at this [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html). Also, keep in mind that the default value for the mutex is to not share it among processes.

also, take a look at these posts [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389353/do-pthread-mutexes-work-across-threads-if-in-shared-memory/2390670#2390670) [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325146/share-condition-variable-mutex-between-processes-does-mutex-have-to-locked-be)

Bonus code to chek the status of the mutex:

```
void showPshared(pthread_mutexattr_t *mta) {
  int           rc;
  int           pshared;

  printf("Check pshared attribute\n");
  rc = pthread_mutexattr_getpshared(mta, &pshared);

  printf("The pshared attributed is: ");
  switch (pshared) {
  case PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE:
    printf("PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE\n");
    break;
  case PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED:
    printf("PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED\n");
    break;
  default :
    printf("! pshared Error !\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return;
}
```

I don't remember were I took this piece of code ... found it! [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/users_57.htm) is the source of hal knowledge.