# Shared memory mutex bug in C

Tags: c, mutex, shared-memory

When running this code the mutex (stored in shared memory between processes) permits the print to run twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(){
    int* shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    pthread_mutex_t* mutex = mmap(NULL, sizeof(pthread_mutex_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

    int cores = 2;
    int is_son = 0;
    for (int core=0; core<cores; core++){
        if (!fork()){   // is son
            is_son++;
            printf("new son\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (is_son){    // only run if is son
        printf("got here\n");
        pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
        if (!*shared){
            *shared = 1;
            printf("is in (should only print once)\n");
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
        printf("left\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example output of wrong behaviour:
[image: Example output of wrong behaviour]

Explanation of the code:
We store in shared memory a boolean called shared and a mutex.
Two slave processes are created. Both try to run the print function, but only one should be permitted to do so.
The mutex is there so only one can enter the protected code at a time, and change shared's value to one, so that the next cant enter.

Comment: Aren't pthreads for _thread_ synchronisation - instead of processes? I think you should use other means of locking here (semaphores i.e).

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390670/694576

Comment: Where do you initialize the mutex?

Comment: Are you expecting two different anonymous mmaps to point to the same memory?

Comment: Not only the mutex must be initialized, special care must also be taken that it might be shared between processes and not only threads. Read the man page for `pthread_mutex_init` and `pthread_mutex_attr_setpshared`.